# Capcha code does not change by page refresh in Yii

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I am trying to refresh the captcha code from the image by this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yw0_button').click(); // captcha refresh
});
```

But this code change the font of the captcha code from the image, NOT the code itself. Is there a way to refresh my captcha code everytime if the page is refreshed ? thx

Comment: just please let me know why my post is voted down. What am i asking wrong ?

Comment: Please do give the reason for voting down atleast. The op has not asked any wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you should use something like this for **refreshing captcha on page refresh**

```
<?php
         $session = Yii::app()->session;
         $prefixLen = strlen(CCaptchaAction::SESSION_VAR_PREFIX);
         foreach ($session->keys as $key) {
             if (strncmp(CCaptchaAction::SESSION_VAR_PREFIX, $key, $prefixLen) == 0)
                  $session->remove($key);
             }
?>
```

Place this just before where you create captcha in your view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer according to [this](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/9203429)

```
<?php 
// click refresh button on page load
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript( 'refresh-captcha', 
'$(document).ready(function(){$("#yw0_button").click();});' ); 
?>
```